# How we can save salt password in database in asp.net identity?

Tags: security, hash, passwords, asp.net-identity

Current I can only see hashpassword saved in my user table in asp.net identity. How can I save salt password in database for the hashpassword in asp.net identity. I need to verify the password also for the save hashpasswords.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know ASP.NET Identity default Password Hasher already uses a random salt to produce the hash. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h83s4e12%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The salt is included as part of the output of the Key Derivation Function.

So my answer would be that you don't need to do that.